# Abrir modal sólo si el formulario está validado

Tags: javascript, modal

estoy tratando de lograr que no se abra la modal hasta que el formulario esté totralmente validado! y no lo estoy logrando! quien me puede ayudar?

```
Este es mi codigo
<form id="formulario" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                                            <label class="lab">Dni:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="Ingresar dni del paciente" required> 
                                        </div>              

                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                                             <label class="lab">Nombre y Apellido:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameAp" id="nameAp" placeholder="Ingresar el dni del paciente" required> 
                                        </div>    
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-4">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button type="submit" id="btnSend" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-2" data-toggle="" data-target="">Realizar consulta</button>
                                                <!-- Modal -->                                      
                                              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog">

                                                  <!-- Modal content-->
                                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">          
                                                      <h4 class="modal-title mr-4 lab">Según lo indicado se pudo determinar:</h4>
                                                      <button type="button" class="close ml-4" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                     <div id="lista-select"></div>
                                                      <p>Agregar alguna observación profesional si corresponde</p>
                                                      <textarea id="observacion" style="width:100%;">

                                                      </textarea>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>
                                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>                                              
                                                </div>
                                              </div>  
                                            </div>                  
                                </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>    

<script>
              // Get the modal
              var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

              var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
              var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
              var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
              img.onclick = function(){
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
              }


              var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


              span.onclick = function() { 
                modal.style.display = "none";
              }

              function validar(form){
               // Estoy probando solo con 2 elementos hasta conseguirlo, luego completaré. 
              if(document.form.nameAp.value=="" || document.form.dni.value==""){
                  alert("Porfavor verifique los datos ya que algunos estan vacios!")
                  return false;
              }  
              else{ 
                  $('#myModal').modal();  
                  return true;
              }
        }

            </script>
```

Comment: Tuve que poner en 2 partes el codigo ya que sino no me dejaba. Agradeceria su ayuda.